# How to open cmd in java

Tags: java, cmd

could you help me please? I am trying to open Command Prompt (CMD) from my Java code, but it gives me an exception. I tried to open other programs like notepad, but it works fine.I see other java programs which I run can't open CMD too. Here is my code.

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k \" " + Methods.getLastfile().getAbsolutePath() + " \" ");`

---

Here are my logs

**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation**

```
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
at gfx.Editor$4.actionPerformed(Editor.java:153)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested               operation requires elevation
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a permissions issue. If that is the case, you will have to create a manifest file that specifies that your application needs administrator permissions.

Here's how to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: But still, my user is the admin of this PC.

Comment: yes but it will fail as java will not bring up the UAC popup asking you to provide admin privileges like other executable apps.

Comment: Okay, got the problem. The problem is that cmd.exe is set to run as administrator. Java does not launch apps which are set to run as administrator. But I don't see compatibility tab in menu in properties. Could you help to prevent cmd run as administrator?

Comment: Please see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560516/stop-cmd-from-always-opening-with-administrator-privileges

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that a Group Policy is in place to *prevent access to the command prompt*. You can verify that by running **gpedit.msc** utility ( `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System`).

A `DisableCMD` key can also be present in the registry at the following location :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System
```

If the value is 0 then the command prompt is disabled for the current user.

Comment: But still, my user is the admin of this PC.

Comment: Well, if you have admin right then remove the policy.